# How to provide default argument as this object?

Tags: c++, default-value

I would like to have declaration like this:

```
void Date::get_days_name(const Date& = this)
```

which I would understand that if no argument is provided use this object as an argument. For some reason in VS I'm getting err msg:

*'Error 1   error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member '*

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are writing illegal C++ code - you can't use `this` in that context. You should think of the parameter list as being "outside" of the class.

Comment: There's not enough context in your code. Is get_days_name() a member function? Are you trying to use the reserved word `this` as a argument name?

Comment: @Neil how can I achive similiar effect?

Comment: Provide an overloaded function which takes no parameters and which does whatever it is you want with `this`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be trying to do this at all.  Why would you do `a.get_days_name(b)` when you could just do `b.get_days_name()`?  If the two forms perform differently, they should be unique functions, in order to make their intent more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make overloaded function:

```
void get_days_name(const Date&) const;
void get_days_name() const {
  get_days_name(*this);
}
```

(BTW, `this` is a pointer, not a reference.)

Answer (score 1):

I like Kenny's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571751/how-to-provide-default-argument-as-this-object/2571769#2571769), but if you are willing to change the parameter from a reference to a pointer you could do it with one function:

```
void Date::get_days_name(const Date* value_ = NULL) const
{
  const Data* value =
    value_ != NULL ?
    value_ :
    this;
  // the rest of the code operates on value.
}
```

Using a pointer more clearly communicates that `value_` is an optional parameter, as well.

However, get_days_name should probably be `static` if it can operate on any `Date` freely.